# IISExpress bandwidth throttling

Tags: iis-express

I have a local IIS 10 Express dev environment setup as part of my testing regime. 90% of the time it does what I need it to, however In order to test some UI status feedback functionality I need to throttle the bandwidth.

Supposedly you just add the `<limits>` node to your `applicationhost.config` file, but it appears to have zero effect on my system.

```xml
<sites>
    <site name="HTML Dev" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="AppPoolA">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\HTML Dev" />
        </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation=":44350:localhost" />
    </bindings>
        <!--bandwidth in bytes per sec-->
        <limits maxBandwidth="1000" maxConnections="4" />
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%AppData%\Microsoft\IISExpressLogs" enabled="true"/>
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%AppData%\Microsoft" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="AppPoolA" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

What am I missing/doing incorrectly?

Comment: That's why it is called IIS Express, not IIS. Many IIS features are not available in IIS Express, and that's intentional.